# Natural join 3 relations which order gives better performance?

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle-sqldeveloper, natural-join

For its optimizing process, Does it join with the relation which has larger result or the one has smaller result?

Answer (score 2):

First. Don't use `NATURAL JOIN`. It is a bug waiting to happen. `NATURAL JOIN` uses fields that happen to have the same name for the `JOIN` keys. It doesn't even take declared foreign key relationships into account.

You can write a query today, and small changes to an underlying table can totally break the query (I admit, this can happen in other ways too). The distressing thing, though, it that the logic is not visible *in the query*.  So use `USING` or `ON` instead.

Second, most databases have an optimization phase. This phase determines the best order for processing. So, even changing the order doesn't have an effect -- because the database engine decides on the order (unless you override it with a hint).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I see how it works now. So how does most databases determine the order for its optimization?

Comment: how does it determine it? It looks at table statistics, indexes, caches, memory, all kinds of things and tries to work out the fastest way to return data. If an index indicates for example that filtering on table X will result in a huge reduction in records for a subsequent join, it may decide to do that first. Basically all you need to know is that a database will give the correct result as quickly as possibly. You can write the same functional query a dozen different ways and most of the time behind the scenes you'll get an identical query plan regardless of what order you put things in